# JSON + PHP + Java - Android login to mysql

Tags: android, mysql, json

i got a problem...
I am trying to store the udid of the device into my database when a user register...
I got this error in the logcat:

```
10-18 17:17:08.141: E/JSON(1712): <br />
10-18 17:17:08.141: E/JSON(1712): <b>Warning</b>:  Missing argument 4 for DB_Functions::storeUser(), called in /home/matbest1/public_html/android_login_api/index.php on line 64 and defined in <b>/home/matbest1/public_html/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
10-18 17:17:08.141: E/JSON(1712): {"tag":"register","success":0,"error":1,"error_msg":"Error occured in Registartion"}
10-18 17:17:08.151: E/JSON Parser(1712): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
10-18 17:17:08.381: D/dalvikvm(1712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 296K, 5% free 9394K/9799K, paused 2ms+4ms
```

I am trying to store the udid in database...
Heres the registeractivity:

```
public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password, String uid){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", uid));

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}
```

Register:

```
UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password, uid);
```

The php code:

```
 public function storeUser($name, $email, $password, $uid) {
    $uuid = $uid;
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details 
        $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
        // return user details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

&

```
  if ($tag == 'register') {
        // Request type is Register new user
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];

        // check if user is already existed
        if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
            // user is already existed - error response
            $response["error"] = 2;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // store user
            $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
            if ($user) {
                // user stored successfully
                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
                $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = 1;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registartion";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid Request";
    }
} else {
    echo "Access Denied";
}
```

Can someone help me? i am new to this... Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` -- Seems as if the JSON you're passing to the jsonParser is malformed.

Comment: So there's some wrong when i parse the udid?

Comment: Read the error message.  It's throwing up on the string `<br`, which is probably the start of a `<br>` tag.  `<br>` tags aren't even legal in JSON, so something's definitely wrong.  Look at the JSON.

Comment: can't i see what's wrong, i am new here, can you help me?

Comment: I don't know how I can help you, other than to tell you that you're JSON is malformed.  You need to figure out why it is malformed.  Stack Overflow is not a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server response contains a PHP error displayed in HTML..

So it's normal that you android app can't parse any JSON..

First thing, you need to be sure that your android app sends all the needed informations (the 4 parameters PHP awaits) because the PHP error clealry tells you that it lacks the parameters #4 : $uid

Try a 
`print_r($_REQUEST);`
at the beginning of your php files to see if PHP receive all the parameters.. If not : the problem is in your android application (uid is a String ? an Integer ? DO you need to convert it ?)